# How to get string based on id from json

Tags: c#, jquery, json

i am giving text as a input and getting responses through text razor API. Now how to get the words(string) based on word position(id).

Here string and id are in different nodes.

**NOTE: Here getting  word position 0,1 I want to display   "The Tiger"  in my front end using Jquery**

### JSON

```
{
    "response": {
        "sentences": [{
            "position": "0",
            "words": [{
                "position": "0",
                "token": "The"
            },
            {
                "position": 1,
                "token": "Tiger"
            }],
            "nounPhrases": [{
                "id": "0",
                "wordPositions": ["0", "1"]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

### What I have Tried

```
var entailments = data["entailmentsAnalysis"];
        entailments = JSON.parse(entailments);
        var Razorentailments = entailments["response"]["nounPhrases"];
        for (var i = 0; i < Razorentailments.count; i++) {
            html = '';
            html += '<tr><td>' + Razorentailments[i]["wordPositions"] + '</td></tr>'
            $("#TextRazorEntailments").append(html);
        }
```

### My Json format

```
"response": {
        "sentences":[],
         "nounPhrases":[]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack exchange! when posting questions try to clearly explain what you're trying to accomplish, what you tried, and what went wrong. Here, it looks like you're missing what went wrong.

Comment: The "what you have tried" part is also missing. This is a coding assignment, not a question.

Comment: yea sure,added now can you check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `data["entailmentsAnalysis"]` is outside of what you have provided but I've adjusted accordingly.

**EDIT - Adjusted to accommodate change in JSON requirements**

```
var entailments = data["entailmentsAnalysis"];
var json = JSON.parse(entailments);
var sentenceList = json["response"]["sentences"];
var nounPhraseList = json["response"]["nounPhrases"];
for (var i = 0; i < nounPhraseList.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < sentenceList.length; j++) {
        var html = '<tr><td>';
        var wordList = sentenceList[j]["words"];
        for (var k = 0; k < wordList.length; k++) {
            if (nounPhraseList[i].wordPositions.indexOf(wordList[k].position.toString()) != -1) {
                html += wordList[k].token + " ";
            }
        }
        html = html.slice(0, -1);
        html += '</td></tr>';
        $("#TextRazorEntailments").append(html);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not working,  for (var j = 0; j < sentenceList[i]["nounPhrases"].length; j++) here error.because nounphrase is not a child of var sentenceList = json["response"]["sentences"];

Comment: Can you please check my question again.Added my json format. @Tubs You posted answer ["response"]["sentences"] is root.but that one is wrong.I added my json format in my ques.

Comment: Your JSON at the top under the heading "JSON" is incorrect then. In that example nounPhrases is indeed a child of sentences. Please ensure ALL examples are accurate else any help will be rendered useless.

Comment: I have modified the code to work with your "JSON Format" example rather than your "JSON" example

Comment: wordPositions also array under nounphrases,how to modify that one?

Comment: Look to `if (nounPhraseList[i].wordPositions.indexOf(wordList[k].position.toString()) != -1)`

Comment: But iam not getting results?

Comment: Fix your JSON in your OP. I'm not going to answer any more questions until you provide me with correct information. The two JSON examples conflict.

Comment: Check my my full json file @tubs sorry for inconvenience

Comment: tq so much i got solution...!